# Node app.js returns Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

This is what my app.js file looks like:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Connect to Mongoose
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/bookstore');
var db = mongoose.connection;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Running on port 3000...');
```

When I do a node app, I get this error:

```
~/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:242
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                      ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:873:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:896:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1077:14)
```

I have searched through StackOverflow, but all of the similar posts are just similar, but not specific to this one. I thought it may have been an issue with mongodb not being installed. I did a brew install mongodb and then I did a mkdir -p /data/db, then ran mongod, but I got an error there. I have not posted that error because frankly I don't even know if I am on the right track.

Comment: what is mongo error? include into post

Comment: Are you sure, you have the mongoDb running in your system?

Comment: Is your Mongo service running? `brew services start mongodb`

Comment: You need to install mongo

Comment: ps -ef | grep mongod

Comment: Mike, that command you provided did the trick. So it was a database issue. My gratitude to all of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got an error when you tried to run mongod, which means you weren't able to start your database service.  That's why you can't connect to it.  You are on the right track, but your issue isn't that you can't connect to your database, it's that you can't start your database.